# How to switch displayed image after AJAX process?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I want to switch from a displayed image to another after an AJAX request completes.

Here is the code for the AJAX call:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.item').click(function(){
    var $id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "test.php",
            data: { id: $id },
            success: //
          })
    });
});
</script>
```

Here is the HTML :

```
<div class="item" data-id="1"><img src="image1.png" /></div>
```

If `image1.png` is displayed, I want to display `image2.png` instead.

If `image2.png` is displayed, I want to display `image1.png` instead.

Please, help me to fill the `success` part in the AJAX process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method to find the image child, and then [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to get and set the attribute for the *src* property.

So before the AJAX call, find the image:

```
var image = $(this).find('img');
```

Then in the success function, check the *src* attribute and set it using [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

```
success: function(data) {
    if (image.attr('src') == 'image1.png') {
      image.attr('src', 'image2.png');
    } else {
      image.attr('src', 'image1.png');
    }
}
```

See it demonstrated in the example below:

```js
var urls = [
  "https://i.stack.imgur.com/C92ci.png?s=32&g=1", //image1.png
  "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/8911010cdec4bb9d56b83b6bbbb1f341?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG"
];
$(document).ready(function() {
  //demonstration container- for AJAX request response
  var questionsContainer = $('#questions');
  $('.item').click(function() {
    var $id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    var image = $(this).find('img');
    $.ajax({
      url: "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow",
      success: function(data) {
        var index = urls.indexOf(image.attr('src'));
        image.attr('src', urls[Math.abs(index-1)]);
        /*if (image.attr('src') == urls[0]) {
          image.attr('src', urls[1]);
        } else {
          image.attr('src', urls[0]);
        }*/
        questionsContainer.html('# of Questions: ' + data.items.length);
      }
    });
    questionsContainer.html('...');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item" data-id="1"><img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/8911010cdec4bb9d56b83b6bbbb1f341?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG" /></div>
<div id="questions">Click the image to load # of questions</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.If needed we can use toggle jquery function to toggle between these two images.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.item').click(function(){
        var $id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        var $imgId = $('.item img').attr('src');
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "test.php",
                data: { id: $id , ImageId :$imgId },
                success: function(data){
                  if(ImageId == 'image1.png'){   
                     $(this).attr('src', 'image2.png');                    
                   }
       else{
         $(this).attr('src', 'image1.png');
       }
                }
              })
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: I need `$id` and `data-id` for another purpose in the PHP script (database insert / update). The class of the images is always `item`. Is there a way to code this simple condition in the success part ? `if [image1.png = displayed] then [display image2.png] else [display image1.png]`

Comment: Yea. I think we cannot check whether the img1 is shown or not in success function.We can only check whether it is img1 or not.Will try to work on it like you said, give me mins.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is something like the heart icon from Instagram or twitter : user can click on it to like or unlike a post. Everything is OK except the icon that doesn't change after a click. I managed to reload the page after each click (and asking the database to know which icon to display) but I don't like this solution...

Comment: You need to change the color of the icon only right? why don't you use css to achieve that instead of doing all this? Anyways updated my code and let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: No, there are two different icons (and for some other projects, icons will be totally different). Concerning the last update of your code, it doesn't work as the `data: { id: $id }` disappeared. Can I do this : `data: { id: $id, $id: imgId }` ?

Comment: Yea.Sorry forgot to remove that .Try giving data: { id: $id, ImgId: imgId }  use commas for different parameter

Comment: Do you mean `{ id: $id, ImgId: $imgId }` ? I tried both, it doesn't work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156308/discussion-between-hema-nandagopal-and-guillaume).